# Is there anyway I can add this(circled data) to the addresponseformdata header:[]?? (have attached pic and codesandbox link)

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, web, frontend, software-design

Is there anyway I can add the circled data to the headers:[] upon clicking the submit button?
[image]

CodeSandBox Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-pike-b1zdd5?file=/src/components/AddResponse.js

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way:

```
let index = addResponseFormData.length -1
addResponseFormData[index]["headers"].push(...addResponseAddHeaderFormData)
```

Comment: should i add this in my handleSumbit function? @Lucas

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, yes.